# Page entered after sign in use Devise with Ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, routes

I'm making a platform where people can share things. I have a problem when people sign in, because I want to redirect to a special page, but I can't figure it out, hope someone can help me.

I have another problems too, because I want to make a page on the navbar, where people when they are logged in, can see their pin. I have found out where they can see everyone of the pins, but can figure out how to show their own pins. I have an idea that it is to use:

```
<li><%= link_to "Home", pin_path %></li>
```

but this gives an error, that says:

```
No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"pins"}
```

The `rake routes` is shown under:

```
                   users_show GET    /users/show(.:format)          users#show
                         pins GET    /pins(.:format)                pins#index
                              POST   /pins(.:format)                pins#create
                      new_pin GET    /pins/new(.:format)            pins#new
                     edit_pin GET    /pins/:id/edit(.:format)       pins#edit
                          pin GET    /pins/:id(.:format)            pins#show
                              PUT    /pins/:id(.:format)            pins#update
                              DELETE /pins/:id(.:format)            pins#destroy
          thank_you_inquiries GET    /inquiries/thank_you(.:format) inquiries#thank_you
                    inquiries POST   /inquiries(.:format)           inquiries#create
                  new_inquiry GET    /inquiries/new(.:format)       inquiries#new
             new_user_session GET    /users/sign_in(.:format)       devise/sessions#new
                 user_session POST   /users/sign_in(.:format)       devise/sessions#create
         destroy_user_session DELETE /users/sign_out(.:format)      devise/sessions#destroy
     cancel_user_registration GET    /users/cancel(.:format)        devise/registrations#cancel
            user_registration POST   /users(.:format)               devise/registrations#create
        new_user_registration GET    /users/sign_up(.:format)       devise/registrations#new
       edit_user_registration GET    /users/edit(.:format)          devise/registrations#edit
                              PUT    /users(.:format)               devise/registrations#update
                              DELETE /users(.:format)               devise/registrations#destroy
                         user        /users/:id(.:format)           users#show
                        about GET    /about(.:format)               pages#about
                      contact GET    /contact(.:format)             pages#contact
                      profile        /profile(.:format)             profile#show
                         root        /                              pages#home
```

Hope someone can help me with my two problems

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) To redirect to a specific page after sign in you should override `after_sign_in_path_for` in your application controller (in this case replace current_user_path with the page you want to redirect to):

```
def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
  current_user_path
end
```

[Source https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To%3A-Redirect-to-a-specific-page-on-successful-sign-in-and-sign-out]

2) If you only want to show the pins for the currently logged in user you should modify your pins_controller.rb so the index action only shows the users pins:

```
def index
   @pins = current_user.pins
end
```

Then link to pins_path in your nav bar

```
<li><%= link_to "Home", pins_path %></li>
```

Be sure to add a before_filter to your pins_controller guarantee that the user is authenticated (so current_user can be resolved)

```
before_action :authenticate_user!
```

Comment: I've sent over a pull request on Github with my comments. Be sure to also merge this [commit](https://github.com/eOverby/Sample/pull/1) by @maringan that fixes the problem with the navbar link.

Answer (score 0):

you must add :id to pin_path, something like this:

> pin_path(pin.id)

Comment: it's also giving me an error: undefined local variable or method `pin' for #<#<Class:0x0000010513d480>:0x000001051486a0>

Comment: pin GET    /pins/:id(.:format)            pins#show

you have defined resource**s**, in my opinion You should define **resource** in routs.rb, something like this:

`resource :pin`

In your definition of routs you must call pin_path with pin id, pint_path(1) where 1 - is pin id

Comment: You can read about the routing here: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#resource-routing-the-rails-default